# How to use variables from other consts in javascript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, scope, react-hooks, constants

I'm building an app that fetches the user's location and stores the latitude and longitude in variables. I use those variables to fetch the user's county, state/province, and country using a google API. I have this in an `index.ts` file, so that I can use these `consts` in other files. I am using `useState` to store values to the variables.

First, I want to ask the user for their location. Based on that, it should use `stateName`, `countryName`, and `countyName` display those on a cards in a separate files. How can I do that with this project structure? And how can I use those variables in those card files?

**index.ts**

```
export const getLocation = () => {  
  

  var [stateName, setstateName] = useState(String);
  var [countyName, setCountyName] = useState(null);
  var [countryName, setCountryName] = useState(null);
  var [stateNameshort, setstateNameshort] = useState(String);
  var [countryNameshort, setCountryNameshort] = useState(String);



  const [latitude, setlatitude] = useState(Number);
  const [longitude, setlongitude] = useState(Number);

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(Object);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(String);
    
  useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
            setErrorMsg(
              "Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!"
            );
            return;
          }
          let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== "granted") {
            setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
            return;
          }
    
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setLocation(location);
    
          const latitude = location.coords.latitude;
          setlatitude(latitude);
          const longitude = location.coords.longitude;
          setlongitude(longitude);
        })();
      }, []);
    
      let text = "Waiting..";
      if (errorMsg) {
        text = errorMsg;
      } else if (location) {
        text = JSON.stringify(location);
      }
    


  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocationData();
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  const fetchLocationData = () => {
    async () => {
      fetch(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
          latitude +
          "," +
          longitude +
          "&key=" +
          apiKey
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          const resState = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
            (x: any) =>
              x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_1")
                .length > 0
          )[0].long_name;
          setstateName(resState);
          const resCounty = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
            (x: any) =>
              x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_2")
                .length > 0
          )[0].long_name;
          setCountyName(resCounty);
          const resCountry = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
            (x: any) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "country").length > 0
          )[0].long_name;
          setCountryName(resCountry);
          const resStateShort = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
            (x: any) =>
              x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "administrative_area_level_1")
                .length > 0
          )[0].short_name;
          setstateNameshort(resStateShort);
          const resCountryShort = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(
            (x: any) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == "country").length > 0
          )[0].short_name;
          setCountryNameshort(resCountryShort);
          if (countryNameshort === "US") {
            countryNameshort = "US" + "A";
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
  };
}
```

For example, I want to use `countryName` and display that in a `Text` component. How can I do that?

**CountryCard.tsx**

```
const CountriesCard = () => {
 return (
    <RectButton >
      <Text>{//countryName??}</Text>
    </RectButton>
  );
};
```

**CountyCard.tsx**

```
const CountiesCard = () => {
 return (
    <RectButton >
      <Text>{//countyName??}</Text>
    </RectButton>
  );
};
```

**StateCard.tsx**

```
const StateCard = () => {
 return (
    <RectButton >
      <Text>{//stateName??}</Text>
    </RectButton>
  );
};
```

Comment: It looks like you created a custom hook called getLocation. You likely want to create a container/App component that calls the hook and then have the hook return whichever values you’re interested in. You would then pass these values to the relevant children as props. Make sense?

Comment: A little. Could you give this as an example in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return all the values that you want to access. First, rename `getLocation` to `useLocation` and move the code to a separate file like `use-location.ts`, then add a return statement at the end of this hook like `return { countryName, countyName, stateName };`. Call `useLocation` from a parent component (that will render `CountriesCard`, `CountiesCard`, `StateCard` etc). and pass them the required values.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const { countryName, countyName, stateName } = useLocation();

    return (
        <>
            <CountriesCard countryName={countryName} />
            <CountiesCard countyName={countyName} />
            <StateCard stateName ={stateName } />
        </>
    );

}
```

And in your child components access the values as props. Example:

```
const CountriesCard = (props) => {
    return (
        <RectButton >
            <Text>{props.countryName}</Text>
        </RectButton>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Where do I call the parent component?

Comment: Depends on your app's directory structure, but if you are just learning, then may be just put it in App.tsx or index.ts. I am not so sure about what you mean by "call" the parent component though.

Comment: What I mean is that the parent component is not being used right now, so where would I use it?

Comment: If you used `create-react-app` to create the project, then you can use it in `App.tsx`